# why it doesn't send any request to server?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, clean-architecture, dagger-hilt

my project is based on clean architecture and hilt
I'm trying to request some data from a Web Service which I made with Python.
I don't know why but it doesn't receive any request from app

my apiservice

```
interface Service {

@GET("/question")
fun getQuestion(): Single<Question>
```

my apimodule

```
class ApiModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val okHttpBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor())
    return okHttpBuilder.build()
}


@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideGson(): Gson {
    return GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(" http://25ae1464a63a.ngrok.io")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun bindApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): Service {
    return retrofit.create(Service::class.java)
```

my viewmodel

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(

private val questionUseCaseImpl: QuestionUseCaseImpl,

): ViewModel(){
val questionModel = MutableLiveData<QuestionModel>()
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

fun getData() {
    questionUseCaseImpl.execute()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe({
            it?.let {
                questionModel.postValue(it)
            }
        },{

        }).let {
            compositeDisposable.add(it)
        }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}
```

}
my main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val mainViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel> ()

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.startButton)
     button.setOnClickListener {
         mainViewModel.getData()
     }

     mainViewModel.questionModel.observe(this, {
         it?.let {
             Toast.makeText(
                 this,
                 "${it.first}is ${it.second}",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG
             ).show()

         }
     })
 }
```

And I have no response at all! In logs it seems like I haven't sent any request

Comment: The empty closure in the `subscribe` method in `MainViewModel` throws away any errors you might receive from `questionUseCaseImpl.execute()`.  If you either use the 1-parameter overload of `subscribe` or add an error logging statement, do you see an error?

Comment: Thank you so much it was my protocol I should used https instead of http